# MySQL: consultar una fecha en campo varchar

Tags: mysql

Estoy queriendo buscar una fecha dentro de un campo de MySQL que contiene varias fechas separadas por comas. Ejemplo:

```
tabla_agenda: id (integer) fechas (text o varchar)
```

Ejemplo de la tabla:

```
registro: 1 / 2017-04-04,2017-04-06,2017-04-08
registro: 2 / 2017-04-08,2017-05-08,2017-06-08
```

La consulta que quiero realizar es s`elect * from tabla_agenda where '2017-04-08' in (fechas)`

Pero no me da ningun resultado. Si dejo solo una fecha lo encuentra bien, no toma en cuenta la separación de las comas como conjunto. He probado comillas simples, comillas dobles tanto en el criterio como en los registros

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Si es posible, modifica el diseño de tu tabla. El tener varias fechas en un mismo campo separado por comas viola todos los principios básicos de normalización de los datos, y crea complicaciones innecesarias a la hora de consultar los datos.

Answer (score 1):

Si, como dices, tienes una columna (`VARCHAR` o `TEXT`) con una lista de fechas al modo:

```
2017-04-04,2017-04-06,2017-04-08
```

Y, dada una fecha, quieres saber en qué filas de la tabla se encuentra dicha fecha, puedes hacerlo con un `LIKE`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabla_agenda
WHERE fechas LIKE '%2017-04-08%';
```

Esa consulta te traerá las filas en que se encuentre la fecha `2017-04-08`, porque lo que hay en tu columna no es otra cosa que una cadena.

> #### PD
>
> Estoy de acuerdo con el [comentario de @sstan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60175/mysql-consultar-una-fecha-en-campo-varchar/233516#comment108467_60175) en tu pregunta. Es
> muy probable que tu tabla necesite ser *normalizada*. No es normal ni
> práctico guardar fechas en una lista, usarlas como tal (para cálculos,
> estadísticas u otros) resultará bastante complejo y sujeto a muchos
> errores difíciles de controlar.

Answer (score 0):

A tu consulta le falta el campo donde tienes tu fecha segun yo sería así

```
select * from tabla_agenda where campo_fecha in (fechas)
```

Donde fechas sería una variable que contiene las fechas:

```
'2017-03-04',´´2017-04-01´...
```

Y campo_fecha tu cambo de la tabla `tabla_agenda`

Comment: en verdad necesito que campo_fecha sea una fecha ingresada y no un campo de la tabla.. es en verdad el criterio de búsqueda. muchas gracias igual